# What's ScannerException() in java?

Tags: java, exception

I receive some code which used functional interface in java8, and this is the part of them,

```
private Optional<Token> readToNextToken(ScanContext context) {
    State current = State.START;
    while ( true ) {
        TransitionOutput output = current.transit(context);
        if ( output.nextState() == State.MATCHED ) {
            return output.token();
        }
        else if ( output.nextState() == State.FAILED ) {
            throw new ScannerException();
        }
        else if ( output.nextState() == State.EOS ) {
            return Optional.empty();
        }

        current = output.nextState();
    }
}
```

But I have error at **throw ScannerException()** 
This code is from my java class sample and should be clearly complete.
ctrl+space solutions are not helpful.
I tried lots of searching to figure out this problem but I still missing ScannerException() in my java.lang.Exception library...
find 
Can you help me please?

Comment: What library is this?  I can't find any Javadocs for any of the classes you're using.

Comment: what does the `import ....ScannerException` say?

Comment: Declare it yourself! `public class ScannerException extends Exception { ...`